# Responsive horizontal scroll menu with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a problem with scrollable navigation menubar. I did some work on it and figured out some, but the main part i am unable to do.

```js
var hidWidth;
var scrollBarWidths = 40;

var widthOfList = function() {
  var itemsWidth = 0;
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    itemsWidth += itemWidth;
  });
  //alert(itemsWidth);
  return itemsWidth;
};

var widthOfHidden = function() {
  return (($('.cssmenu').outerWidth()) - widthOfList() - getLeftPosi()) - scrollBarWidths;
};

var getLeftPosi = function() {
  //return $('.item:first-child').position().left;
  return $('.list').position().left;
};

var reAdjust = function() {
  if (($('.cssmenu').outerWidth()) < widthOfList()) {
    $('.scroller-right').show();
  } else {
    $('.scroller-right').hide();
    /*
            var leftPos = $('.item:first-child').position().left;
         $('.item').animate({left:"-="+leftPos+"px"},'slow');
            */
  }

  if (getLeftPosi() < 0) {
    $('.scroller-left').show();
  } else {
    $('.item').animate({
      left: "-=" + getLeftPosi() + "px"
    }, 'slow');
    $('.scroller-left').hide();
  }
}

reAdjust();

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  reAdjust();
});

$('.scroller-right').click(function() {

  $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');

  $('.list').animate({
    left: "+=" + widthOfHidden() + "px"
  }, 'slow', function() {
    //reAdjust();
  });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {
  //var leftPos = $('.item:first-child').position().left;
  //$('.item').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow');
  //$('.scroller-left').hide();

  $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');

  $('.list').animate({
    left: "-=" + getLeftPosi() + "px"
  }, 'slow', function() {

  });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #0090c0;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  /* Main menu border- */
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  /* Main menu plus sign */
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  /* Main menu plus sign */
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul>li {
  height: 35px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #ff6030;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item>a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #c04830;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub:hover>a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}

.scroller {
  color: #333333;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.scroller-right {
  float: right;
}

.scroller-left {
  float: left;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  min-width: 3000px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  /*float:left;*/
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  color: #efefef;
  border: 1px dotted #111;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center>ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover>ul>li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu>ul>li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active>a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:after,
  #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub>a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <div id="menu-button">Menu</div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li name="item"><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-
          home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li name="item">
      <a href="QuickOrderEntry.aspx" target="frmScr">Quick Order</a></li>
    <li name="item">
      <a href="SpreadOrder.aspx" target="frmScr">Spread Order</a></li>
    <li name="item">
      <a href="SwitchOpenMF.aspx" target="frmScr">Switch Order</a></li>
    <li name="item">
      <a href="SpreadViewOrders.aspx" target="frmScr">View Spread Orders</a></li>
    <li name="item">
      <a href="ViewOrder.aspx" target="frmScr">View Order</a></li>
    <li name="item" class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="Blank.aspx" rel="SSI0000001" target="frmScr">Systematic Investment</a>
      <ul id="SSI0000001">
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="frmSIPRegistration.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmrptCancelSIP.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Cancellation</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="frmrptSIPRegistrationView.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Registration 
         Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmrptBrokerSIPReport.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP 
         Installment due Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmSIPCancellationReport.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Cancellation Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_SIP&amp;FileType=IMP_SIP_REG" target="frmScr">SIP Registration Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_SIP&amp;FileType=IMP_SIP_CAN" target="frmScr">SIP Cancellation Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_SHIFT&amp;FileType=IMP_SIP_TO_XSP" target="frmScr">Shift SIP To XSIP Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="SIPExceptionsReport.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Exception Report</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Mandate</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="frmMandateRegistrationForm.aspx" target="frmScr">Mandate 
        Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmMandateUploadByMember.aspx" target="frmScr">Mandate Registration Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmMandateSearchByMember.aspx" target="frmScr">Mandate Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmMandateDownloadForMember.aspx" target="frmScr">Mandate 
          Download</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button">
           </span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="frmXSIPRegistrationMaster.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP 
           Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?
          TransType=IMP_XSIP&amp;FileType=IMP_XSIP_REG" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP 
          Registration Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmRptXSIPRegistrationView.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP Registration Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmRptXSIPInstallmentDueReport.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP 
          Installment due Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmrptXSIPBrokerageReportForMembers.aspx" target="frmScr">Brokerage 
          Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmrptCancelXSIP.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-
           SIP Cancellation</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?
       TransType=IMP_XSIP&amp;FileType=IMP_XSIP_CAN" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP 
       Cancellation Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmXSIPCancellationReport.aspx" target="frmScr">X-SIP / I-SIP Cancellation Report</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">SWP</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="SWPRegistrationMaster.aspx" target="frmScr">SWP Registration Master</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_SWP&amp;FileType=IMP_SWP_REG" target="frmScr">SWP Registration Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_SWP&amp;FileType=IMP_SWP_CAN" target="frmScr">SWP Cancellation Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="SWPCancellationRegn.aspx" target="frmScr">SWP Cancellation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">STP</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="STPRegistrationMaster.aspx" target="frmScr">STP Registration Master</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?
           TransType=IMP_STP&amp;FileType=IMP_STP_REG" target="frmScr">STP Registration 
           Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?
          TransType=IMP_STP&amp;FileType=IMP_STP_CAN" target="frmScr">STP 
          Cancellation 
           Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="STPCancellationRegn.aspx" target="frmScr">STP 
           Cancellation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="item" class="has-sub">
      <span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="Blank.aspx" rel="SGB0000001" target="frmScr">SGB</a>
      <ul id="SGB0000001">
        <li><a href="SGBManualEntry.aspx" target="frmScr">SGB Manual Entry</a></li>
        <li><a href="SGBView.aspx" target="frmScr">SGB View</a></li>
        <li><a href="SGBUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">SGB Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="item" class="has-
            sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="Blank.aspx" rel="MADM000001" target="frmScr">Admin</a>
      <ul id="MADM000001">
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Member M 
            Masters</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="MemberBranches.aspx" target="frmScr">Member 
            Branches</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button">
            </span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">User Master</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="UserMasterDetails.aspx" target="frmScr">User Master Manual</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserMasterUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">User Master Upload</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Client Details</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="ClientMasterDetails.aspx" target="frmScr">Client Master</a></li>
            <li><a href="FATCA.aspx" target="frmScr">FATCA Manual Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="CKYC.aspx" target="frmScr">CKYC</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">
          <span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Admin Reports</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="frmrptBrokerSIPReport.aspx" target="frmScr">SIP Installment due 
            Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="UserMasterReport.aspx" target="frmScr">User 
            Master Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="ClientMasterReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Client Master Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmClientStatusReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Client Status</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="RptBranchLoginInfo.aspx" target="frmScr">Branch/Login Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="RptMemberAMCList.aspx" target="frmScr">Member AMC List</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmViewBannedClients.aspx" target="frmScr">View Banned 
           Clients</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button">
           </span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Limits</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="BranchDeposits.aspx" target="frmScr">Branch Deposits</a></li>
            <li><a href="DealerDeposits.aspx" target="frmScr">Dealer Deposits</a></li>
            <li><a href="ClientDeposits.aspx" target="frmScr">Client Deposits</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ClientPaymentRejections.aspx" target="frmScr">Payment 
           Rejections</a></li>
        <li><a href="UploadFATCAFile.aspx" target="frmScr">FATCA 
           Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="AOFDownload.aspx" target="frmScr">AOF 
           Download</a></li>
        <li><a href="ImageUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">Image 
           Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="MemberBankDetails.aspx" target="frmScr">Member 
           Bank Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="PANUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">PAN 
           Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="item" class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span>
      <a href="Blank.aspx" rel="MMR0000001" target="frmScr">Member Reports</a>
      <ul id="MMR0000001">
        <li><a href="ProvORDReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Provisional Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="RptProvisionalOrderReportNew.aspx" target="frmScr">New Provisional  
            Orders </a></li>
        <li><a href="OCNReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Bulk OCN 
            Generation</a></li>
        <li><a href="CustodianProvOrderReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Custodian Provision Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="OrderLogReport.aspx" target="frmScr">Order Log</a></li>
        <li><a href="OrderDetailsSearch.aspx" target="frmScr">Order Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="RptOrderStatusReportNew.aspx" target="frmScr">New Order Status</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="item" class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button">
             </span>
      <a href="Blank.aspx" rel="UTI0000001" target="frmScr">Utilities</a>
      <ul id="UTI0000001">
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="Blank.aspx" target="frmScr">Member 
             Related</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="QuickOrderEntry.aspx" target="frmScr">Quick 
             Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="PlaceOrderRedemption.aspx" target="frmScr">Minimum Qty Redemption Order Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="ViewOrder.aspx" target="frmScr">View Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="BulkFileUpload.aspx?TransType=IMP_MASTER" target="frmScr">Bulk Upload 
             New</a></li>
            <li><a href="FileUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">Bulk Upload</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="UploadClientDealerMap.aspx" target="frmScr">Upload 
              Client Mapping &amp; Balances</a></li>
            <li><a href="ManualFileUpload.aspx" target="frmScr">Upload Client Deposits</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmUpdateClientDealerMapping.aspx" target="frmScr">Upload Client 
              Dealer Mapping</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmUploadOrderCancellation.aspx" target="frmScr">Upload Order Cancellation</a></li>
            <li><a href="DealerDeposits.aspx" target="frmScr">Dealer Deposits</a></li>
            <li><a href="frmUploadMemberFundsForGateway.aspx" target="frmScr">Upload Member 
               Funds Gateway</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ChangePassword.aspx" target="frmScr">Change Password</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li name="item"><a href="LogOut.aspx" target="_top"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Log 
               Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Link: https://www.bootply.com/RDP650rMxv

I need a scrollable navigation menu with chevron left and right over it and if the extreme corner menu has sub menus it is exceeding the screen resolution.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself. Do not just add a link to your code. Many people are blocked from code sharing sites, and the sites themselves go out of business on occasion. Without the code here on Stack Overflow, this question will not be helpful for future viewers.

Comment: I didnt got your problem clearly. are you trying to get rid of the horizontal scroll from the menu ?

Comment: No, exact the opposite Joe, i want a scroll bar menu, my header menu count is above  25, i need to show all the main menu into header navigation menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

if I got it right, the last menu when opens submenu shoots to extreme right. you can fix it with this css

```
ul#UTI0000001 li ul {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```